# Disable LiveWare manager

Tags: applications, bloatware

I have rooted my Sony Ericsson Neo V by downgrading to .42 and using Zergrush, without unlocking the boot loader. Now I want to remove the LiveWare service. NoBloat and similar apps don't show it. How can I delete or at least disable this serivce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in `/system/app/` for `com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.apk` or similar.  Remove it and any .odex file with the same name if present and that should get rid of it.  (Note that I have no idea if this is required by the system or will otherwise screw up your phone, so do it at your own risk.)

Comment: The file was called LiveWareManager.apk and removing it doesn't seem to have any ill effects.